# 2 Columns for UL LI, But one column will contain more LIs than the other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a UL LI list and display inside 2 columns.  It looks fine with 5 items in the first columns and other 5 in the second column.

Problem: I need to show 8 items in the first column and 2 items in the second one.  I try some ways, but it doesn't work as expected.

Should I get Jquery involved to get it works? 
Please help.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/07gxdo8y/1/)

```css
div#multiColumn {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="multiColumn">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item1</li>
    <li>List Item2</li>
    <li>List Item3</li>
    <li>List Item4</li>
    <li>List Item5</li>
    <li>List Item6</li>
    <li>List Item7</li>
    <li>List Item8</li>
    <li>List Item9</li>
    <li>List Item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how the flow of styling of multi-column works -- if you want to control what is in two lists you will have to do it a different way (eg make two lists and then style those to be left and right coluns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `break-after: always;` on the 8th `li` element:

```css
div#multiColumn {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

#multiColumn li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-column-break-after: always;
  break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<div id="multiColumn">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item1</li>
    <li>List Item2</li>
    <li>List Item3</li>
    <li>List Item4</li>
    <li>List Item5</li>
    <li>List Item6</li>
    <li>List Item7</li>
    <li>List Item8</li>
    <li>List Item9</li>
    <li>List Item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
div#multiColumn ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="multiColumn">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item1</li>
    <li>List Item2</li>
    <li>List Item3</li>
    <li>List Item4</li>
    <li>List Item5</li>
    <li>List Item6</li>
    <li>List Item7</li>
    <li>List Item8</li>
    <li>List Item9</li>
    <li>List Item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Paulie for sharing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using display flex, with flex wrap. Provide you should set the height of ul element.

Advantage of this approach is that you can have responsive height if required and you can wrap to any number of columns based on width of the items.

Refer the code snippet below.

```css
div#multiColumn ul{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height:160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="multiColumn">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item1</li>
    <li>List Item2</li>
    <li>List Item3</li>
    <li>List Item4</li>
    <li>List Item5</li>
    <li>List Item6</li>
    <li>List Item7</li>
    <li>List Item8</li>
    <li>List Item9</li>
    <li>List Item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Narayanan for sharing this experience.